# toggle element doesn't work with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to execute a JQuery toggle function (it toggles an input field to make it accessible to the client) only if a certain condition is met. (I'm testing for the condition using JavaScript.) Can I do this? For some reason, the JQuery toggle function doesn't work when I set it inside the JavaScript function, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if this can't be done at all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function conditionalToggle()
{
   if (conditionIsMet)
   {
      // JQuery toggle call here
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If it works outside but not inside then either `conditionIsMet` is falsey or the host function is not being invoked, add some alerts to see which

Comment: Yes, more info.  Perhaps show code where you are calling conditionalToggle, and what jQuery function in that function.

Comment: That should work if jQuery is loaded before this function and the function is properly called. Can you paste in the whole code or set up an fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't use jQuery right, or don't execute the function, or (the most common mistake of new jQuery users) don't wait for the DOM to be ready:

```
function foo(){
    if ("foo" === "foo")
        $('#elementId').toggle();
}

$(function(){ // functions inside $() runs after the DOM is ready.
    foo();
});
```

Where `elementId` is a place holder to your element id.
[**Simple DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nEUM8/)

---

Note that you can use this `toggle` overload:

```
$('#elementId').toggle(showTheElementOrNot);
```

`toggle( showOrHide )`
`showOrHide` A Boolean indicating whether to show or hide the elements.

[**jQuery docs**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery should work if inside a ready() function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   function conditionalToggle(){
      if (conditionIsMet) {
         $(element).toggle();
      }
   }
});
</script>
```

or just do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function conditionalToggle() {
       if (conditionIsMet) {
          element.style.display = element.style.display=='block' ? 'none' : 'block';
       }
    {
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it when DOM is ready, if you've still problem, you can do also like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function() {
        conditionIsMet && $('#elementId').toggle();
   });
</script>
```